# How to delete an Excel WorkSheet in the solution explorer Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

I have created some sheets but now I cannot delete them.

When I right-click on it it doesn't show a remove button and I try to click on delete on my keyboard and neither

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmV4E.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried removing them locally just using file explorer?

Comment: At some point maybe you should ask this off the Visual Studio tooling team as well? If anything, It seems like a feature request or bug

Comment: No repro. I created an XLSX file in the project folder. Then i used _Add Existing Item_ to add it to the project. I'm able to right-click _Exclude from project_ and right-click _Delete_. Now, I've never met a program that doesn't take a lock on an XLSX file when it opens it, so _Delete_ will fail if the file is open.

Comment: I think in some situations the solution explorer is set to readonly. Right-click at this time will not have the remove button. I'm not sure if it is during debugging. Can you check it out and provide a more complete screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, but I already discarded the project. but the problem was presented without debugging and the only thing that I could not eliminate was the sheet